# Problem installing MySql2 gem

Tags: rubygems, mysql2

I have already checked the many topics on this site about this error and haven't found anything that helps. I'm very new to this. I'm using Windows Server 2003 R2.

When I invoke:

```
gem install mysql2
```

I get this error:

```
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.
3.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.6/ext/mysql2/ge
m_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Following this [link](http://rorguide.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-192-and.html)

I used the command `gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'`

and worked for me.